# Pandas map specific rows of column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to map the values of a column in my DataFrame, but only where a condition of another column is satisfied. To select the rows which are to be mapped I can simply use .loc, and then modify them as:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,2,3,1,2,3,2], 'col_2':[100, 'information/string', 'information/string', 4, 600, 'information/string', 7, 'information/string']})

relevant_rows = data.loc[data['col_1']==2]
relevant_rows = data.apply(lambda x : x.split('/')[0] if '/' in x else x)
```

The problem is how do I combine the relevant_data dataframe with the original dataframe? My attempt at doing this was:

```
data.loc[data['col_1']==2] = relevant_rows
```

But this doesn't work, I think since the .loc[] operator as used here returns a copy of the DataFrame rather than the DataFrame itself...

Is there a quick way to achieve what I need?

The DataFrame I am trying to edit looks like:

```
col_1   col_2
1   100
2   information/string
2   information/string
3   4
1   600
2   information/string
3   7
2   information/string
```

And my target is:

```
col_1   col_2
1   100
2   information
2   information
3   4
1   600
2   information
3   7
2   information
```

i.e. all the rows where there are strings in col_2 are edited.

Comment: Can you show what dataframe you expect to get in the end?

Comment: @mikksu I have updated the question to show what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
data.col_2.replace('/.*','', regex=True, inplace=True)
data
   col_1        col_2
0      1          100
1      2  information
2      2  information
3      3            4
4      1          600
5      2  information
6      3            7
7      2  information
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just do:

```
df['relevant_rows'] = df['col_2'].apply(lambda x : x.split('/')[0] if '/' in x else x)
```

Comment: This won't work as the dtypes of the data in 'col_2' are mixed

Comment: I've updated the answer, you solution won't work as I can apply the mapping to every item in col_2